# Duplicate rows based on other column values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, row

I would like to duplicate rows by column `Count`. For sample data, my code works fine, but when I try to use a large data set, I get the error:

> Error in rep(seq_len(dim(df1)[1]), df1$Count) : invalid 'times' argument

My data & code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Month = rep(month.abb[1:12],10,replace = TRUE), Product = paste0('Product ', rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 12)),
                  Count = sample(c(1:10),120, replace = T),  stringsAsFactors = F)


df2 <- data.frame(df1[rep(seq_len(dim(df1)[1]), df1$Count), , drop = FALSE], row.names=NULL)

head(df2)
  Month   Product Count
1   Jan Product A     1
2   Feb Product A     4
3   Feb Product A     4
4   Feb Product A     4
5   Feb Product A     4
6   Mar Product A    10
```

I have data composed of 45000 rows and 5 columns, including 4 being characters and 1 numeric. And for this data I get above error.

Comment: What happens if you use `rep(1:(dim(df1)[1]), df1$Count)` instead of `rep(seq_len(dim(df1)[1]), df1$Count)`? Make sure `Count` has no negative values `rep("A", -3)` produces `Error in rep("A", -3) : invalid 'times' argument`.

Comment: The same error: ```invalid 'times' argument```.

Comment: `table(df1$Count)` produce? Are there any negative numbers there?

Comment: Yes, I have a few rows with NA.

Comment: Can you paste the output of ```table(df1$Count)``` as suggested by @deepseefan?

Comment: But ```table(df1$Count)```don't show rows with NA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way. This handles negative and `NA` values.

```r
df2 <- data.frame(df1[rep(seq_len(dim(df1)[1]),  with(df1, ifelse(Count > 0 & !is.na(Count), Count, 1))
), , drop = FALSE], row.names=NULL)
```

Rows where `Count` is negative or `NA` will be kept as they are (meaning they will be copied to `df2` once without a repeat).